# color mismatch with dual monitor setup

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, colors

I have a Samsung LC24F390FHNXZA and an HP Compaq LA2205WG, and try to do a dual monitor setup. I connected them to my GTX 1050 card (Samsung is connected by HDMI, HP is connected by DVI) but have a color problem. There is no problem with the Samsung monitor, but the HP color is incorrect.

[image: Samsung]
[image: HP]

EDIT:

I have tried changing contrast, sharpness, color management, and applied sRGB on the windows display setting.

Comment: Is there no way to adjust color on the monitor?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik i have adjusted the color, contrast, and RGB setting. the picture on the right is the best I can do so far.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's no question. OP is stating facts and observations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a pretty normal thing - and there's a lot of elements there, including panel type, age, calibration or lackthereof.

I've even bought identical monitors which didn't match out of the box, and used a (borrowed) hardware caliberator to match.

Looking at your monitors, one is 'curved' which I believe indicates its OLED (so  perfect contrast), and newer. The compaq company hasn't existed for years, so its an older monitor with a CCFL backlight (which will dim and yellow with age potentially).

Even *with* hardware calibration and a lot of work, getting them *identical* is impossible. Without it - the built in Calibrate display monitor setting is your best choice, and I tend to use that with an old copy of clickmonitorddc so I can change brightness and contrast in software.

Practically though, you're not going to have much luck with monitors *that*  different